# webdriver getCurrentUrl adding symbol "/" at the end of URL

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Good day everyone!

I wrote a test to check site redirects. WebDriver open  wrong URL and site back-end should redirect to correct address.

Example: 
opened url:  **http://lenal.eu**
expected url: **https://lenal.eu**

In browser command line I see correct address after redirect.
But **getCurrentUrl**  return address with "/" at the end of URL and test failing. 
I've tried get current url from metatag link rel="canonical" but received the same result with "/"

```
@Test(dataProvider = "Links collection", dataProviderClass = RedirectParser.class)
public void redirects(String execUrl, String expUrl) throws IOException {
    //System.out.println(execUrl+"======"+expUrl);
    open(execUrl);
    System.out.println("Executed URL: "+execUrl+" Actual page URL: "+url() + " Expected page URL: "+expUrl);
    System.out.println($(byXpath("/html/head/link[@rel='canonical']")).getAttribute("href"));
}
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Triming the character I guess would work. For those wondering, I'm not the OP. I'm just another Andrew.

Comment: Why is it a problem? Will that not go to the same page ?

Comment: @Chai This is a problem because received URL by webdriver not equal atual URL in browser command line

Comment: @FlorentB. I know how compare several values. The main question in difference things. According to the CEO standards all URL with "/" at the end should be redirected to page without "/"

Comment: @Andrew Yeah, I know, but this not resolve the main problem)))

Comment: So you are doing something like Assert.assertThat(openedUrl, equalTo(expectedUrl)) ? If that is the case you can choose either to trim the url, removing the last character (like Andrew suggested), or start with with an url with / like www.lenal.eu/  , or you can use a partial match using something like containsString instead of equalTo.

Comment: Oh I now see your recent comment. If that is the test then you should anyways start with a www.lenal.eu/ as openedUrl and then trim it, to compare to expectedUrl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way Web works. There is nothing like `http://example.com` it is always `http://exampe.com/` because the path requested from the server is `/`.

The browsers do show you the url without `/` but the `/` is still there

[image: location]

See how the browser shows `https://stackoverflow.com` and `document.location.href` is `https://stackoverflow.com/`. This is just javascript and not even selenium into picture yet. So don't blame selenium for this. This is an expected behavior

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that copying the URL from the bar will also add an empty path at the end.